# Logout redirects to /forums/

Tags: logout

A while back I installed a plugin which, upon logout, re-directed users to `/forums/`.

Unfortunately, I have no idea which plugin that was and whether or not it's still active/installed.

What code/db settings can I look for to remove the offending code?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered the Hikari Hooks Troubleshooter (http://hikari.ws/hooks-troubleshooter/) this weekend to find what plugins were loading my header with competing open graph metadata.

Enable it, and visit the frontend. There will be a modal dialog over your site which should list the hooks into wp_logout. One of these will be the offending plugin.

If you're still using the other parts of the plugin and there are no settings to turn that feature off, you should be able to remove it by adding `remove_action('wp_logout', $plugin_function)` to your theme's functions.php.

Make sure you disable HHT when you're done with it.

Comment: Got it! It was Simple:Press, and `Hikari Hooks Troubleshooter` gave me the hint: `sp_logout_redirect`. Found the option in the plugin now :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Search your WordPress database: `SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_value LIKE '%forums%';`
2. The option_name of the returned rows should give you a pointer to the offending plugin